# Circuit Testing failed (Reverse polarity and Buck-Converter)

Tags: buck, failure, reverse-polarity

[image]

Hello guys,

today I tested my circuit. Its a simple Reverse Polarity Protection Circuit with a Buck-Converter. As I supplied voltagae to my circuit, everything was well (3.5V output). Going higher with the voltage was okay, too. Until I got to ~30V. Then my power supply gone into current limitation.

I think my TVS Diode (which I choosed too small..) gone to Breakdown Volatge and caused a short circuit (is that possible?). I Supplied voltage only to the pins of the Buck but its still not working, so I think something destroyed the buck but exactly what?

EDIT: With "the buck dont work" I mean, when I supply voltage to my circuit, my power supply goes into current limitation because the circuit wants to drain a lot of current. So if I dont supply from J1 and J5 and supply the IC pins of the buck directlyy its the same failure.

---

Datasheets:
[Buck](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2841.pdf)

[PMOS](https://www.vishay.com/docs/77707/sqj409ep.pdf)

[Bipolar TVS](http://www.taiwansemi.com/products/datasheet/SMBJ%20SERIES_O1701.pdf)

[Schottky](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2552646.pdf?_ga=2.238833477.472586155.1519808263-1948773863.1517218358)

[Zener](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MMSZ2V4T1-D.PDF)

Comment: not going to work unless you connect `bat+`

Comment: I only connect Bat+ and Bat-

Comment: not what the digram shows.

Comment: Now you know it.

Comment: C1 is 6 to 10 times bigger than the examples in the data-sheet

Comment: @HarrySvensson What you mean with (1)? Bat+ needs to be connected, it is the Input for my Circuit. J1 is + and J5 is -. To (2) the datasheet is for different Diodes with different Voltages, take a closer look to the Datasheet. And yes, I know its a buck and its should be a buck too.

Comment: @Jasen Yes in the examples but take a closer look to the text and not just the images.

Comment: @FatihY The (1) is weird because I can see it and Jasen and you can't.

Comment: I see it now, the vertical on the "+" is less than 1 pixel wide :(

Comment: @HarrySvensson Explain it to me, I really cant see it

Comment: @FatihY I'm so extremely confused right now. I can see it, Jasen can see it (now). You are the one who made the image and you can't see it. - Uhh... Okay.. what?... I don't even... anyways... You corrected me with the SMBJ24CA so I deleted my earlier comment and then looked in the datasheet for that specific item which has a breakdown voltage of 26.7-32.6 V. So this is the obvious culprit. Which you... know about.... Is this a trick question? Am I being pranked? What is happening? Are our eyes real?

Comment: I try to take the TVS now (need it for later testing) and propably need to replace the buck

Answer (score 1):

1. TVS can fail in shorted mode, it is actually the preferred failure mode as it still protects the circuit against overvoltage.
2. TVS is (without additional components) usually not suitable to clamp sustained overvoltage. It is intended for clamping voltage spikes (short duration) If you check your datasheet, the 600 W applies to pulse only (it is actually more energy limit than power limit). Sustained power absolute maximum is 3 W only, with 30V drop it is 100 mA only.
3. It is well possible that your C2 capacitor failed as well. What is its voltage rating? [Typical overvoltage failure mode of MLCCs](https://www.murata.com/en-us/support/faqs/products/capacitor/mlcc/qlty/0002) is short circuit.

Comment: 2. Shouldnt the diode behave like a zener diode at the breakdown voltage? The breakdown voltage is min. 26.7V to 29.5V and the supply voltage was max. 31V. To 3. the voltage rating is 50V

Comment: 2. Yes, exactly. So about 30 V drop and whichever current your power supply allows to flow. Calculate I*U and you have dissipated power (likely too much).

Comment: 3. OK, it was just my guess. It would be good if you can describe "not working" buck in greater details in your question. Measure voltages at various points etc.

Comment: Do you think the the TVS caused a short circuit? 3. Read the EDIT in my question, I tried to explain it better

Comment: Yes, overloaded TVS very likely fails into the short circuit. About your edit (just to be sure) -- when testing the buck only, you disconnect the circuit with MOSFET and TVS from the buck part, right?

Comment: No, I didnt and this was my mistake. Now I removed the TVS and it works now (buck not damaged). Thank you for your help :)